# Django Admin does not display pre-existing objects

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-admin

I created a class for exposing Django-Admin to multiple databases as explained in Django docs.

My admin.py looks like this

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import DestinationMap


class MultiDBModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # A handy constant for the name of the alternate database.
    using = 'supplierui'

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Tell Django to save objects to the 'other' database.
        obj.save(using=self.using)

    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        # Tell Django to delete objects from the 'other' database
        obj.delete(using=self.using)

    def queryset(self, request):
        # Tell Django to look for objects on the 'other' database.
        return super(MultiDBModelAdmin, self).queryset(request).using(self.using)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ForeignKey widgets using a query
        # on the 'other' database.
        return super(MultiDBModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request=request, using=self.using, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ManyToMany widgets using a query
        # on the 'other' database.
        return super(MultiDBModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request=request, using=self.using, **kwargs)



admin.site.register(DestinationMap, MultiDBModelAdmin)


#admin.site.register(DestinationMap)
```

The admin interface displays the model name, but has 0 objects.

The table contains 275 objects, I have confirmed that using sql.

I cannot find any solution to this as of now.
Help would be appreciated.

Comment: `The table contains 275 objects` then why on earth did you ` created a class for exposing Django-Admin to multiple databases as explained in Django docs`  this feature is for situations where you have tens of millions of records and can no longer scale vertically

Comment: @e4c5 Because I'm using multiple databases, and I need to add objects to this table periodically (and manually). If my approach is wrong, could you please explain me how do I do the task? I am using a Postgres database to hold 2 tables, one with about 10M records and one with currently 275. I need to add records to the latter using django-admin.

Comment: I really don't see why you can't add this table to the existing DB. But this question cannot be answered with out a lot more details such as your settings, router etc

Comment: @e4c5 I am not using the default database, and am doing manual routing as of now, through `.using('dbname')` . Tell me what details do you require and I'll provide you with the same. Also, could you still tell me, why are the table objects not visible? Thanks!

Comment: It should be `get_queryset(self, request)` Can you change and try

Comment: @RajaSimon It is not working, I get an error saying 'super' object has no attribute 'queryset'

Comment: @HarshitDhawan yeah. you need to change that as well...

Comment: @RajaSimon Could you write an answer with the necessary edits please? I am new to Django!! Thank you so much!

Comment: One sec... let me answer this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `get_queryset` function

```
from django.contrib import admin

# Register your models here.
from .models import DestinationMap


class MultiDBModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # A handy constant for the name of the alternate database.
    using = 'supplierui'

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        # Tell Django to save objects to the 'other' database.
        obj.save(using=self.using)

    def delete_model(self, request, obj):
        # Tell Django to delete objects from the 'other' database
        obj.delete(using=self.using)

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Tell Django to look for objects on the 'other' database.
        return super(MultiDBModelAdmin, self).get_queryset(request).using(self.using)

    def formfield_for_foreignkey(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ForeignKey widgets using a query
        # on the 'other' database.
        return super(MultiDBModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_foreignkey(db_field, request=request, using=self.using, **kwargs)

    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request=None, **kwargs):
        # Tell Django to populate ManyToMany widgets using a query
        # on the 'other' database.
        return super(MultiDBModelAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request=request, using=self.using, **kwargs)



admin.site.register(DestinationMap, MultiDBModelAdmin)
```

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: Do I have to make changes to add/delete new objects as well?

Comment: I don't think so bcse you alreadyadded `save_model` and `delete_model`

Comment: I get an error when I add a new object, "duplicate key value violates unique constraint "supplierui_destinationmap_pkey" " as it does not save the model at the end of the auto primary key, id.
How can I make it do that